# How to use Google Calendar APIs resource __init__ constructor?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a service account with python for the Google Calendar API to display my own calendar to a site without having to login first.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(
    os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'static/calendarSync/service-account.json')

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

google_account = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    'calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

service = google_account.__init__()
```

In order to call the same methods that the API offers (calendarList, etc.) do I need to do the init?
If so how would I fill these parameters: self, http, baseUrl, model, requestBuilder, developerKey, resourceDesc, rootDesc, schema? If not how does one call the calendar methods on this object?

Comment: What do the [docs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/start.md) say? You don't usually call `__init__` manually, it's the constructor. That being said, I'd suggest you to start by reading a bit on Python fundamentals first.

Comment: The example I was following is here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#python_1 It used the sqladmin API rather than calendar, and for sqladmin it looks like you can call the instances method but that is not available for calendar.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the Calendar with Python Quickstart [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python)

So in order to get the calendar list for instance, you have to first build the Calendar service, like this:

```
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
calendar_list_entry = service.calendarList().get(calendarId='calendarId').execute()
print calendar_list_entry['summary']
```

Also, please bear in mind that you *have to* perform the domain wide delegation in order to get the expected result.

#### Reference

- [Calendar API Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python);
- [Package googleapiclient](http://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient-module.html).

Comment: I believe this is the answer, however, when I try to call .calendarList().get(calendarId='calendarId').execute() I get an error "Instance of 'Resource' has no 'calendarList' member" Do you know what would be causing this? I have set up the domain-wide delegation.

Comment: Are you sure you want to get `calendarList` and not `calendars`. You can take a look at this entry [explaining the difference](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#calendar_and_calendar_list). 
I would follow @ale13 advice and just copy and paste the Python Quickstart, and work from there